# A "constexpr" function should not be declared "inline"

Tags: c++, destructor, sonarlint, inline-functions, constexpr-function

By analyzing code using *SonarLint*, I got a message (the title of the question) about a **destructor** that is declared like below:

```
class Foo
{
public:
.   // default ctor
.   // parameterized ctor
.
    inline ~Foo() = default; // dtor
.
.   // copy ctor = delete
.   // copy assignment operator = delete
.   // move ctor
.   // move assignment operator

private:
    ...
    mutable std::vector< std::vector<char> > m_Matrix;
    ...
};
```

Here is the [message's description](https://rules.sonarsource.com/cpp/RSPEC-5408):
**Declaring a function or a static member variable constexpr makes it implicitly inline.**

I don't think the dtor of this class can be `constexpr` or `consteval` because it has a non-static data member of type `std::vector` so `~Foo` has to call `delete[]` at some point to deallocate the vector's storage.

So why is *SonarLint* showing this message? Is it because of  `= default`? Does any **defaulted** special member function become implicitly `constexpr`?

Comment: Even ignoring constexpr, every member function defined in class body is implicitly inline.

Comment: Manually defining an empty/default destructor is almost always a mistake, unless you also define the copy/move operations. It silently replaces copying your class with moving, e.g.: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/GTzdE9azs

Comment: @HolyBlackCat So even making it ` = default` will mean that it's implicitly inline?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat My class has a move ctor and a move assignment operator and also I have deleted both copy ctor and copy assignment operator. Is this setup ok?

Comment: Yes, it's ok in that case. But you can remove it completely, and nothing will change.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Oh ok. But what exactly do you mean by "remove it completely"? Should I remove the declarations and definitions of move ctor and move operator and also remove the deleted declarations of copy ctor and copy operator? And also remove the declaration of the defaulted dtor? Is this the ***rule of zero***? What about the def ctor and parameterized ctor? I don't think I should remove them.

Comment: @digito_evo "remove it" likely meant "remove the destructor (defaulted) definition".

Comment: @digito_evo When you define a function inside a class definition, it is implicitly defined as inline. `~Foo() = default;` is considered a definition, so it will be inlined automagically.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant remove the defaulted destructor. But regarding the move operations, if they only move `m_Matrix`, then they should be `=default`ed, and deleted copy operations can optionally be removed, because they're deleted automatically when you have custom (or defaulted) move operations. Or, if you don't mind the class being copyable, you can remove remove both copy and move operations.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I was looking for that. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @NathanOliver I understand. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The only use case for a defaulted destructor I have seen is `virtual ~Foo() = default;`. when you *need* to have a virtual destructor in a base class, but it has nothing to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes:

> An explicitly-defaulted function that is not defined as deleted may be declared `constexpr` or `consteval` only if it is constexpr-compatible ([special], [class.compare.default]).
> **A function explicitly defaulted on its first declaration is implicitly inline ([dcl.inline]), and is implicitly constexpr ([dcl.constexpr]) if it is constexpr-compatible.**

(From [Explicitly defaulted functions](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.default#3), emphasis mine.)

Foo is likely constexpr-compatible in C++20, because `std::vector` can now be `constexpr`.